# Merge cells in each row

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I know how to merge cells, I know how to merge columns, and I know how to merge tables. However is there any way that I can merge all cells in a row over numerous rows? So to clarify further, I have three rows in my Excel sheet as below:

```
First Name    Middle Name    Last Name
John          James          Smith
Sally         Anne           Lavery
Tom           John           Doe
```

I need to be able to merge these cells in each row to look like this:

```
Name
John; James; Smith
Sally; Anne; Lavery
Tom; John; Doe
```

So 3 rows all with one cell. I have been able to find a method to do this for 1 row but if I extend my range it merges them all into one cell instead of 3 rows:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Sigh As String
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Range("A18:I19")
Sigh = ";"
xOut = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xOut = xOut & Rng.Value & Sigh
Next
With WorkRng
    .Merge
    .Value = VBA.Left(xOut, VBA.Len(xOut) - 1)
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work through your selected range row by row:

```
Sub Test1()

    MergeRowByRow Range("A18:I19")

    'or if you want a different delimiter:
    MergeRowByRow Range("A18:I19"), "|"

End Sub

Sub MergeRowByRow(SourceRange As Range, Optional Sigh As String = ";")

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim xOut As String

    For Each rRow In SourceRange.Rows
        xOut = ""
        For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
            If rCell.Value <> "" Then
                xOut = xOut & rCell.Value & Sigh
            End If
        Next rCell
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        rRow.Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If Len(rRow.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
            rRow.Cells(1).Value = Left(xOut, Len(xOut) - 1)
        End If
    Next rRow

End Sub
```

I've updated so blank cells will not result in two consecutive delimiters, and if end result is a blank cell it won't error out when removing the last delimiter.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, however there is one issue some rows don't have any information in the 'middle name' column. With this query it still places in the ;, so it looks like John;;Doe. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I've updated to take the double delimiters into account - and if that results in an empty cell it won't crash when trying to remove the last character.

Comment: Perfect, This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi here a simply code with 2 way.
I test two range A2:C3 (first, middle, last name) and the some date on A11:C13
change it to your

```
Sub CompactNameIntoOneCell()
Dim str As String
str = "name" & vbCrLf

    For i = 2 To 4
        For Each cell In Range("A" & i, "C" & i)
            str = str & cell & ","
        Next cell
        str = str & vbCrLf
    Next i
' if you want only one cell
Range("A2", "C4").ClearContents
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Value = str

'if you want merce the range into one cell
Range("A11", "C13").ClearContents
Range("A11").Select
Selection.Value = str
Range("A11:C13").Select

    Selection.Merge
    With Selection   'format to your like
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The same result can be had with the following script after you selected with the mouse the portion you want to process the script on:

```
    sub Merge_Text()
        for each c in Selection
            if c.Value <> "" then c.Value = c.Value & "; " & c.Offset(0,1).Value & "; " & c.Offset(0,2).Value
            c.Offset(0,1).Value = ""
            c.Offset(0,2).Value = ""
        next
    end sub
```